# SVG fill="url(#foo)" disappears when SVGs are loaded dynamically

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, svg, fill

I am loading different SVGs dynamically within a web application built in AngularJS, I am also altering the opacity of layers within the SVGs. These SVGs have some paths with the fill pattern property as such

```
<defs>
  <pattern id="glass-floral" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="184" height="272">
    <image xlink:href="../img/glass-floral.png" x="0" y="0" width="184" height="272"/>
  </pattern>
</defs>

<rect x="98.3" y="85.5" fill="url(#glass-floral)" width="365" height="318.8"/>
```

This all works great at first- however under some conditions these # fills simply disappear:

-

**Condition 1**:
If I were to switch to another SVG and back.

**Result:**:
The # fill is still visible.

-

**Condition 2**:
If I were to alter the opacity of the element with the # fill.

**Result:**:
The # fill is still visible.

-

**Condition 3**:
If I were to both switch to another SVG & alter the opacity of the element with the # fill.

**Result:**:
The # fill becomes invisible.

-

This is to mean the styles all appear to still be applied normally in the code- but there is no actual visible fill to be seen. This behaviour exists as far as I can see in Chrome and slightly differently in Safari. Firefox seems to be immune.

I've tried manually flicking the element to another fill and back in the browser to see if perhaps something had cached, no luck. I still think this may somehow be the case, with how the # refers to an inline pattern defined in the `<defs>` which may not have been loaded yet by the AJAX but the cached CSS rule still floating around.

If it helps matters, both SVGs that I am switching between both have the same `<defs>` and CSS styling applied. Is perhaps the double case of the defined pattern causing an issue?

Comment: Presumably browser bugs, have you tried reporting them to the appropriate bugtrackers?

Comment: @RobertLongson I have found a workaround which would suggest this (answered in question), will report to Chromium etc. when I finish work.

Comment: @jmcgrory, chromium developers are still waiting for your feedback https://crbug.com/712328

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some investigation this appears to be an issue with the browsers (Chrome/Safari possibly others) not being able to keep up with rendering fill: url(#) ***and*** opacity for the same element at the same time, at least in cases of multiple/dynamically loaded SVGs.

To solve this, apply your opacity css to a containing  element around the element that has the fill: url(#), example below:

```
<defs>
  <pattern id="glass-floral" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="184" height="272">
    <image xlink:href="../img/glass-floral.png" x="0" y="0" width="184" height="272"/>
  </pattern>
</defs>
<style>.opacity-class { opacity: 0.33; }</style>
<g class="opacity-class">
  <rect x="98.3" y="85.5" fill="url(#glass-floral)" width="365" height="318.8"/>
</g>
```

This allows the browser to do both independently and not ruin your pretty pictures.

Comment: What do you mean multiple SVGs, you're not loading multiple SVGs with the same/duplicate id values are you because that's invalid.

Comment: No- I am switching between different SVGs which share the same css style sheet for their classes/groups.

Answer (score 1):

I had multiple `svg` elements and problem was the same ID of all `pattern` tags. So, **using different `id=""` for the `pattern` tag of each `svg`** element solved my problem with disappearing `fill="url()"` on dynamic reload...